# Hold the component's rendering until the store has finished hydration

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm fetching my initial data like so:

```
export function populate (dispatch) {
  let posts = []
  dispatch(requestNews())
  fetch(someEndPoint)
  .then(payload => payload.json())
  .then(items => {
    //some fetching logic that populates posts list above
  })
  .then(() => { dispatch(receiveNews(posts)) })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}

function request () {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_NEWS,
    payload: {
      populating: true
    }
  }
}

function receive (posts) {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_NEWS,
    payload: {
      populating: false,
      posts
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see above I'm setting the store with a field called populating which starts as false and changes to true when the 'request' is dispatched and then back to false when 'received' is dispatched.

Then my component looks something like the following:

```
import { populateNews } from '../modules/news'

class News extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    //this.mapPosts = this.mapPosts.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    populateNews(this.props.dispatch)
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.props.news.populating) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.news.posts[0].title}
        </div>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <div>loading</div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

On initial load render is being called before the store is populated with the fetched posts even though my populate switch changes back and forth as expected.

I've tried dealing with it using a local state on the component, so it's constructor has: `this.state = {populating: false}` and then the action creator changes that, but got the same result.

So at the moment my solution is to instead check if the state has a slice called 'posts' which is being created after the content is fetched and if it does to render it. like so:

```
 render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.news.posts ? <div>{this.props.news.posts[0].title}</div> : null }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This of course just renders the component and then renders it again after the store is updated with the posts, and is not an optimal solution like waiting with the render until the fetch is completed and the store is populated.

There's a long discussion about it here: 
https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/210

How can I delay or better put condition the render itself?

Comment: I think the best way here would be to hydrate the store with the accurate data on initial load if initial load means the very first visit your user does.

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to do but as I've said above the component renders before the store is hydrated although I'm using the fetch in componentWillMount and a state switch to hold the rendering until the fetch is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you might want to change your if statement. Unless your store is initializing `populating` to true, it will be `undefined` on the initial load and will pass your `if (!this.props.news.populating)` validation which will try to render the post title. Change your condition to look for a truthy value rather than a falsey value and you should have more control over it.